# Sales Force getting refresh token using ZKForce

Tags: ios, salesforce, access-token

I am using ZKForce to integrate Sales Force into my app. Till now I am successful but now I am facing a problem regarding refresh token.

When I am logging in to sales force from my application I am doing the following.

```
- (void)loginResult:(ZKLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (result && !error)
    {
        NSLog(@"session id is %@",result.sessionId);
        [SFAccountManager sharedInstance].coordinator.credentials.accessToken = result.sessionId;
        NSLog(@"Login Successful");
    }
    else if (error)
    {
        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection failed" message:@"Failed connecting to server. Please try again" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [myAlertView show];

    }
}
```

Here I am just setting the access token and not setting the refresh token.

I downloaded the sample case memo app and it has the following when successful log in.

```
- (void)loginOAuth:(FDCOAuthViewController *)oAuthViewController error:(NSError *)error
{
    if ([oAuthViewController accessToken] && !error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Logged in to Salesforce");
        [[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] setClientId:kSFOAuthConsumerKey];
        [[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] setApiUrlFromOAuthInstanceUrl:[oAuthViewController instanceUrl]];
        [[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] setSessionId:[oAuthViewController accessToken]];
        [[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] setOAuthRefreshToken:[oAuthViewController refreshToken]];
        NSLog(@"oauth token is %@",[oAuthViewController accessToken]);
        NSLog(@"oauth token is %@",[oAuthViewController refreshToken]);
        [self.splitViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.oAuthViewController autorelease];

        // STEP 3 b - Save OAuth data after login
        [self saveOAuthData: oAuthViewController];

        [self didLogin];
    }
    else if (error)
    {
        [CaseMemoAppDelegate errorWithError:error];
    }
}
```

In here they are setting refresh token.

So how do I get that refresh token from my code. Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Refresh token is only relevant for OAuth flows, not the standard login.  If your first piece uses standard login (username/password submitted directly), you won't get a refresh token.  If you do use OAuth, then your code can basically present the refresh token you get upon first logon to the server, and get a new access token back (needed when the current one expires).

Comment: How to check if its expired or not??? Whenever I log in the access token I get is same. But if I keep the app idle for long time and try to access the data its throwing error.